# Force PERL script to use portable perl

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, batch

I have been developing my scripts using Strawberry perl installed in C: drive (5.20.11) I've now installed the portable version on my USB stick. (5.28.xx) Whatever I try, it ALWAYS reverts to the primary version in C:

I know this as I put this at the top of the script (print $];) and always comes back as 5.2011.

I tried using a modification of the standard Strawberry bat file that starts the USB version of perl

```
@echo off
if not "%1" == "/SETENV" setlocal
set PATH=%~dp0perl\site\bin;
sample.pl
pause
```

... thinking that would set the path to the required version, but still loads from C: drive !!

I tried the above path line as the first line of script,(no ball -fact the script will run without ANY shebang?)

Not to mention the shortcut link which uses "explorer.exe" so I can add the "..\script_path\sample.pl" in the Target field  ... (that method doesn't work with cmd.exe in target. With a link after the program name, all it does is open CMD with directory set to "RunMe") which then complains that "sample.pl" is not a command or script. (Even tried "perl sample.pl" ... as you would enter in CMD will not  work)

OK,so end user will not have two versions running ... but that don't help me any !

(After lunch, will try changing name of C:Strawberry so it can't be found at boot up ... but that seems a little drastic!)

NB: On stick, it's "strwawberry/perl/bin/perl.exe",the other is "R:\School Programs\sample.pl", "School Programs\sample.bat" and shortcut is "R:\RunMe\sample.bat" in the target field.(Start In is empty ... I can't set this as Drive letter will vary from user to user !)

Totally lost !!

Answer (score 0):

However you invoke the batch file, simply running `sample.pl`

- doesn't guarantie the current dir **IS** the batch files folder `%~dp0`
- replacing the system variable `path` will cut you off from any other needed exeutables
- uses the association/file type resp. `"hklm\software\classes\.pl"` from the registry to identify the program to execute the .pl file with and **NOT** your version.

So better run **your** perl.exe and pass sample.pl as an argument.
**EDIT: changed path to perl.exe** due to [@JosefZ](https://superuser.com/questions/1422500/force-perl-script-to-use-portable-perl/1422524?noredirect=1#comment2147184_1422524)s hint

```
@echo off
if not "%~1" == "/SETENV" setlocal
set "PATH=%~d0\strawberry\perl\bin;%path%"
"%~d0\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" "%~dp0sample.pl"
pause
```

Comment: Maybe `%~d0\strwawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe` instead of `%~dp0perl\site\bin\perl.exe` considering the OP's note _NB: On stick, it's "strwawberry/perl/bin/perl.exe"_?

Comment: @JosefZ Yes you are right, I overlooked the `NB`

Comment: Ahhh ... that's one glaring error I didn't see, the extra 'site\' folder that doesn't exist !!

Comment: Thanks LotPings. (Funnily enough, I just thought of starting perl  each time -and modifying the portable bat file -  when I want to start a new script ... rather than have it running in background, and then passing items to it) I'm used to simply calling a script via browser. So - on a tangent - whilst the Apache server runs all the time, when you call a perl script, does it run and then terminate, to start afresh when it next encounters next shebang?

Comment: Further to the comment about 'cutting me off  from other executables', I have installed other CPAN modules to the USB. Will they still run from the "%~dp0sample.pl"? Am I right in thinking "%~dp0" only covers the drive letter, so as "sample.pl" is in a folder off root ("R:/School Programs/sample.pl") I also need to add that folder?

Comment: I'm no Apache speciaist, I think it depends on the configuration. Overwriting/replacing the `Path` variable will no longer search for files not in the current folder, if you want to access files on the USB without explicitly including the path you'll need to add those folders also to the (changed) path.

Comment: Tried it.but no go because of the folder off root. Entered "%~dp0\School Programs\sample.pl" and it came back "R:\School" is not a recognised  as a command.(Simple solution: replace space with underscore, but just curious how you get around space

Comment: With proper double quoting that shouldn't be a problem. So the USB is drive R: and sample.pl is **not** in the same folder as the batch file?

Comment: Yes, used double quotes, but it didn;t like the space. The script works OK =IF= it is in the "R:" root ... but place it in a folder, and it complains it cannot find the path specified. (Tried altering sample to relative, but no go. So wondering if the path itself has also got to be relative?"

Comment: Seems the "path to perl" "script name" part ARE relative paths

Comment: Tried this from shortcut in "RunMe" (%windir%\explorer.exe "..\School_Programs\sample.bat") ... and it opens up "My Documents on C: drive to select a file !!!! "R:\RunMe\shortcut" "R:\School_Programs\sample.bat" and "sample,pl"

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trial and error, I found that (so far) it seems to work without the use of a batch script, using a CMD shortcut, and relative links to the location of the script. So the command I am now using in the "Target" field is C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe \k "..\strawPerlPort\perl\bin\perl.exe ..\School_Programs\sample.pl"

It does make rather long link in the title bar of the CMD title bar, but at least it works as neither "Target" or "Start In" accept relative paths or "%~dp0" (My theory is CMD.exe is loading perl, and in turn, perl is loading the script